# mysql - how to get all differences from one table to another (huge amount of rows ~ 500k)

Tags: mysql, select

In the

```
`synchro_newitems`
```

table I have all new items (from external source) ~ about 500k rows. It has one column:

```
`new_ids`
```

In the

```
`synchro_olditems`
```

table I have all current items (also from external source) ~ about 500k rows. It has one column:

```
`old_ids`
```

I must get only the new items from `synchro_newitems`:

(NEW ITEMS) = `synchro_newitems` (-) `synchro_olditems`

I tried do that by insert the differences to the 3rd table:

```
INSERT INTO `synchro_diff` (`id`) 
SELECT DISTINCT new_ids FROM synchro_newitems 
LEFT JOIN 
synchro_olditems ON synchro_newitems.new_ids = synchro_olditems.old_ids 
WHERE synchro_olditems.old_ids IS NULL
```

(similarly with "NOT IN")

It's works for small amount of rows. But fails when there are 500 000 rows to compare.

I've tried simple:

```
DELETE FROM synchro_newitems WHERE exists(SELECT * FROM synchro_olditems)
```

But it dosent work.. Do you know some smart method to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a weirdness of mysql queries.  Try this:

```
select distinct new_ids
from synchro_newitems n
where not exists (select 1 from synchro_olditems o where n.new_ids = old.old_ids)
```

This optimizes better.  And, better yet, put an index on o.old_ids to make it go blazing fast.

Comment: amazing! of course should be

where n.new_ids = o.old_ids

;-)  but It works great!